# Need Help on SQL code: Stuck on this questions since yesterday

Tags: mysql

I have the following data with columns in this particular sequence (transaction_id,Customer_id,transaction_date,Sales).

```
Insert into transaction_test values(6566354,0844632,'2019-04-30',4);
```

I am looking to solve the following question:

I need total transactions that a customer makes in their first 90 days. Need one row per Customer ID

The code that I am writing is as follows:

```
Select customer_id
     , Count (*)
     , transaction_date
     , MIN(transaction_date) 
  FROM transaction_test
 GROUP 
    BY customer_id
     , HAVING DATEDIFF(transaction_date,MIN(transaction_date))<=90;
```

This code is not giving me the required answer. I was wondering if anyone of you might help me here.

Comment: Their first 90 days of what? You mean 90 days from their first transaction?

Comment: Yes, 90 days from their first transaction.

Comment: "not giving me the required answer", the question is, does it give you anything at all? You probably do not want `transaction_date` without the MIN function in the SELECT clause, otherwise you're going to get 1 group per transaction date. You also don't want the DATEDIFF expression in the HAVING clause, you would want it in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Thanks Strawberry and Lasse! what should be the correct query code for this question?

Answer (score 1):

E.g.:

```
SELECT a.customer_id 
     , COUNT(*) total 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT customer_id
            , MIN(transaction_date) first_order 
         FROM transaction_test 
        GROUP 
           BY customer_id
     ) a
  JOIN transaction_test b
    ON b.customer_id = a.customer_id
   AND b.transaction_date < a.first_order + INTERVAL 90 DAY
 GROUP 
    BY customer_id;
```